# how to read my json and send it to an email in pure nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js, express

I would like NodeJS server, `post.js` file, to send the json object from the AJAX request to an email using only pure NodeJS.
The following is the front-end code that sends the AJAX request:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("#contact").submit(function () {
        var data = {};
        $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function (key, value) {
            data[value.name] = value.value;
        });
        data.interest = [data.interest1, data.interest2, data.interest3];
        delete data.interest1;
        delete data.interest2;
        delete data.interest3;
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "post.js",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#contact").addClass('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#contact").addClass('error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: really new to nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/) offers a great way to have your node.js server send emails with easy setup. With this you can set up a simple node server such as:

```
//untested node.js code only for reference. 
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('TODO: setup your SMTP');

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
 var mailOptions = {
 from: "TODO: sender",
 to: "TODO: recipient",
 text: req.body
}
app.listen('TODO: some port');
```

Check nodemailer's documentation for details on setting up the server to suit your needs.